# What is this kind of material?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, materials

I'm trying to recreate an image on 3D (As you can see on the picture) but the material doesn't ''shine'' on the borders like the original picture.
I was thinking on adding textures but this is for an animation, so maybe a better setup for a material could help more than just a plain texture (which is no problem, i have Zbrush software too)
**What's the kind of material that i could use to get some kind of 'texture' or 'ilumination' like the original/real picture?**

Or if you have any other idea, what can you recommend? I'm starting with cycles rendering...

[image]

Comment: You might want to have a look at the *Fresnel* and *Layer weight* nodes.

Comment: That is one massive node setup you want . . . people would either charge you big $$ to come up with that or be bored for several hours :-|

Comment: Gandalf! it worked!!! now i just need to apply a texture image plus that kind of ''effect''

Comment: Besides a Fresnel this OSL shader could be useful for this: http://www.swineworld.org/2013/10/osl-lace-curtain-shader-for-blender.html

Comment: You could add some emission into the mix or do a post processing pass that enhances the edges. http://www.blender.org/manual/composite_nodes/types/filter.html

Comment: @gandalf3 you made the answer!

Answer (score 4):

The top image seems to be the rods and cones that line your retina. The image is likely from a scanning electron microscope, then manually colored. (SEM can't see color)

Fresnel is the easiest way to accomplish the effect.

[image]

Comment: This has already been addressed in the comments, notify the person who suggested it to post as an answer if it solved the issue.