# How can i create the shader of the virus?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shaders

[image]

I've been trying, but my result is not convincing at all

here it is:
(Note that the model is missing a subsurf)
[image]

here the node setup
[image]

Thank you

Comment: why are you not satisfied? maybe put a bit of translucency at the end?

Comment: Improving your lighting setup will also be important to get closer to the reference image

Comment: @moonboots you mean another mix after the one with sss and the diffuse?

Comment: @ajwood thank, i'll try

Comment: Have you tried using the Principled BSDF?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23571/what-is-this-kind-of-material

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, maybe you should try *Subsurface Scattering* at the end of your node organization, it will give translucency and it will take your volume into account:

[image]

Comment: thank, i'll try it